# Bootstrap Multilevel Dropdown Menu Not Extending

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, multi-level

I am experiementing with a multi-level dropdown menu using Bootstrap, I have made sure I have the most up to date version of Bootstrap. My code is pretty straight forward. The problem is the sub levels are not extending (not showing).

I suspect there is something wrong with the html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#" id = "Service_1" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Service 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
    <a class="trigger right-caret">Color</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
      <li>Green</li>
      <li>Red</li>
      <li>Blue</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li>
    <a class="trigger right-caret">Names</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
       <li>James</li>
       <li>Mike</li>
       <li>Bob</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/9vzk9x9e/3/

Please share your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: could you provide the script code?

Comment: Bootstrap does not provide "multi-level submenus". Where is your CSS rules for .dropdown-submenu?

Comment: @stratovarius please see the added script file

Comment: @Khalid T  see above

Answer (score 1):

Did you include whether the jQuery?
By the way you can write corrsponding JS script in order to have a multlevel submenu, like the code below :

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
        var current=$(this).next();
        var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
        if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
            $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
        var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
        root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
    });
});
```

Here is the good example to have a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/yxkut/16/

Comment: This is the exact example I am learning from. But it does not work on my machine. @stratovarius

Comment: Also I am using the same css as in that fiddle

Comment: strange, could you provide your example in jsfiddle?

Comment: also, do you have jquery connected? place this code `var online = navigator.onLine; alert(online);` at the beginning of your script and see whether it returs true or false.

Comment: could it be that it's because I put the script file in a script.js

Comment: The jsfiddle does not include jquery cdn, so I guess this was the issue. Download jquery and connect to you local code, also repeat the css code as well since it provides the arrow which allows to see dropdown levels. Here is the working code in Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/EaPsdTG0JxEdGNBcvVb8

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with CSS only. Here is how:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="...">
  ...
  <li class="dropdown-submenu" role="presentation">
    <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Menu item 1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="...">
      <li><a role="menuitem" href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a role="menuitem" href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* DROPDOWN SUBMENU */
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
          border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
  background-color: #f88e1d;
  background-image: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  border-width: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-submenu:hover > a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-submenu ul {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: T thanks, but I am also curious about why the version with javascript does not work

Comment: I think your JSFiddle works. I've just tested it. You just need to enable jQuery 1.12.0 in the Javascript panel (and set "Load type": onDomready)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The issue was in my css, I left out this part.

```
.right-caret:after
{   border-left: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
.left-caret:after
{   border-right: 5px solid #ffaf46;
}
```